# How to do a wildcard file replacement during build in angular projects?

Tags: angular-cli, angular-builder, angularbuild

I have an angular2+ project with scss styles. I'm targeting 2 apps: mobile (ionic) and web with the same codebase.

Due to the need to load totally different stylesheets for some of the components, I'm thinking to do the following: save **web** styles for each component in `xxx.component.scss` (no change), and save **mobile** styles for each component in `xxx.component.mobile.scss`

My question: is there a way to replace `xxx.component.scss` files with their `xxx.component.mobile.scss` counterpart when building the angular project, similar to what angular does with environment files (replaces `environment.ts` with `environment.dev.ts` if the configuration is dev)?

I tried using wildcards in angular.json like this, but it didn't work:

```
"fileReplacements": [
    {
      "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
      "with": "src/environments/environment.dev.ts"
    },
    {
      "replace": "src/**/*.scss",
      "with": "src/**/*.mobile.scss"
    }
  ]
```

Is there a way to do a wildcard file replacement during build in angular projects? What is the recommended way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not supported by angular.json. As a workaround, you can use the environment resolved in the `environment` file, and replace individual scss files inside the .ts file accordingly, as below:

```
import { environment } from 'src/environment/envitonment';

isIonic = environment.name === 'ionic';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-xxx',
  templateUrl: './xxx.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ isIonic ? './xxx.component.mobile.css' : './xxx.component.css']
})
```